# Rearranging Columns on Mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to rearrange two columns on mobile devices (xs displays) but I'm running into trouble using the push/pull method. All of the documents I can find on this are using an even number of columns on each side, however in my case I'm using 7 - 5.

How would I readjust this example to make it so the green column appears on top on mobile devices only and remains the way it's on desktop screens.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7">
      <p id="red" class="text-center">
        Content
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <p id="green" class="text-center">
        Content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kzy5rcau/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch the ordering for the stacking on mobile, then push/pull on the sm size.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-push-7">
      <p id="green" class="text-center">
        Content
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-pull-5">
      <p id="red" class="text-center">
        Content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kzy5rcau/3/